# System Update from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates

I've done a big update on my PC. He asked me if I want to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10 but I don't know if I can lose some data or something..can someone explain me this situation? Thanks in Advice!

Comment: You can do the update, normally it works, but just in case is always a good idea to have backup of important information.

Comment: This is an unsupported upgrade path and considering the big changes in 17.10 not recommended. I would wait for 18.04.